# Alpha Clamp an Image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, transparency

I have various images of shadows.

[image: shadow]

I need to round the opacity of all pixels that actually have a color, to either 0% or 100%, depending on their original opacity.

Here's all pixels below 25% opacity set to 0%, and the rest set to 100%:

[image]

Here's all pixels below 75% opacity set to 0%, and the rest set to 100%:

[image]

These bottom 2 images were created using an image effect in a video game engine. I need to re-create this effect ideally in Photoshop, but could probably get by in another image editor. These images are on a transparent background which I need to retain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the first image to create a layer mask on a black filled layer.
2. Select the mask thumbnail in the layers panel.
3. Do a Threshold adjustment, and move the slider as you like.

An example

[image]

Comment: `Layer > Transparency > Threshold alpha` will work just as well in the simple cases.

Comment: I'm not seeing a "Transparency" option under the "Layer" menu, is that the correct place?

Comment: Yes, for Gimp see [here](https://i.imgur.com/mlLTNOG.png)